# Bug in IE retrieving get variable within button?

Tags: php, internet-explorer, variables, get

What the hell is wrong with IE? So I have some basic code like this:

```
<button><a href="index.php?showpage1">Show page1</a></button>

if (isset($_GET['showpage1'])) {


echo "some stuff";
}
```

This works in every browser except Internet Explorer 11 (did not test older browsers). I have taken out the link from within the button tags and it worked. I also have tried encapsulating the button within the link tags and guess what it: does not work.

When this happens my URL in IE also looks weird with a name attribute from a different HTML element!

Any thoughts on this problem?

Comment: Just a hunch, but try wrapping your `href` tag in quotes -> `href="index.php?showpage1"`

Comment: Ow sorry, in my actual code it is wrapped in quotes :)..

Comment: You cannot have a clickable element inside a clickable element.

Comment: Ah some browser just playing nice eh. I guess it is not allowed by HTML5 then? Well guess I have to restyle divs into buttons or maybe I will go with javascript to get the result so I don't need links :)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML5 Button Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element):

> Content model:
>       Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant.

[Interactive content](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#interactive-content-0):

> Interactive content is content that is specifically intended for user
>   interaction.
>
> ```
> a
> audio (if the controls attribute is present)
> button
> embed
> iframe
> img (if the usemap attribute is present)
> input (if the type attribute is not in the Hidden state)
> keygen
> label
> object (if the usemap attribute is present)
> select
> textarea
> video (if the controls attribute is present)
> ```

So as [PeeHaa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/508666/peehaa) already pointed out in the comments: `a` inside `button` is explicitly not allowed by the spec.